# Moving divs out of screen

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the following setup.

```
<div class="elegant-1">
  <div class="hold-1">
    <div class="image-1"></div>
    <div class="image-2"></div>
    <div class="image-3"></div>
    <div class="image-4"></div>
    <div class="image-5"></div>
    <div class="image-6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have this setup...

```js
var divs = $('div[class^="hold-"]').hide(),
  i = 0;
(function cycle() {
  divs.eq(i).fadeIn(900)
    .delay(6000)
    .fadeOut(900, cycle);
  i = ++i % divs.length;
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elegant-1">
  <div class="hold-1">
    <div class="image-1">1</div>
    <div class="image-2">2</div>
    <div class="image-3">3</div>
    <div class="image-4">4</div>
    <div class="image-5">5</div>
    <div class="image-6">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hold-2">
    <div class="image-7">7</div>
    <div class="image-8">8</div>
    <div class="image-9">9</div>
    <div class="image-10">10</div>
    <div class="image-11">11</div>
    <div class="image-12">12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="hold-3">
    <div class="image-13">13</div>
    <div class="image-14">14</div>
    <div class="image-15">15</div>
    <div class="image-16">16</div>
    <div class="image-17">17</div>
    <div class="image-18">18</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason I would like the following setup is because I would like to scroll through my divs and move the previous divs out of the page while introducing the next div and just have this on a constant loop. I know how to fade the divs one by one by using the above JavaScript.

However, I would like an animation moving them out of the screen and introducing the next one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where does the second setup come into play? And if you want some other animation use [`animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate) to set animations.

Comment: The second setup is what I would like it to be. Currently, I have images overlapping each other creating a distorted photo (images 1-6). Then I would like to move that (hold-1) out of view and introduce (hold-2) which holds (Images 7-12).

Comment: If you are animating them all anyway why the separate containers? Or did you mean you want to fadeIn/Out the images in each container and then at the last image move the container out, and the new container in, repeat

Comment: I guess I just don't know how to do the animation continuously without pressing a button or hovering. I would like it to happen on a delay automatically.

Comment: Animations aside, you need to use the data attribute. Change `class="image-1"` to `class="image" data-image-1`. Then use `$('.image')` to select the images and `dataset.image` to get the image index.